selenium miss Cloudflare,after use driver.switch_to.window() can't pass verification anymore
enter image description here
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")

newwindow = 'window.open("https://xslist.org/zh/searchByImage")'
driver.execute_script(newwindow)
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])

directly use
driver.get("https://xslist.org/zh/searchByImage")

or after the code pass
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])

I can't pass the verification anymore by manual, seems to recognize the driver attachment. But without driver attachment I can't click the bottom.
how to deal it?
